# Jobby/SuperClosure not working: The file containing the closure, "... : eval()'d code" did not exist

Tags: php, serialization

I'm trying to use [Jobby](https://github.com/jobbyphp/jobby) with PDO as my cronjobs manager. I've used [SuperClosure](https://github.com/jeremeamia/super_closure) (which is used by Jobby as well) to serialize my closure and insert it to database. Then I get all records from my database and I unseralize the closure before adding it as job to Jobby but all I get is:

> root@test:/home/.../public_html/public# /usr/local/bin/php ./cron.php
>   PHP Notice:  Serialization of closure failed: The file containing the closure, "/home/.../public_html/vendor/jeremeamia/SuperClosure/src/SerializableClosure.php(210) : eval()'d code" did not exist. in /home/.../public_html/vendor/jeremeamia/SuperClosure/src/SerializableClosure.php on line 117
>   
>   **Notice**:  Serialization of closure failed: The file containing the closure, "/home/.../public_html/vendor/jeremeamia/SuperClosure/src/SerializableClosure.php(210) : eval()'d code" did not exist. in **/home/.../public_html/vendor/jeremeamia/SuperClosure/src/SerializableClosure.php** on line **117**

Here is my code:

```
$config = array(
    'output' => ROOT_PATH . 'closure.log',
    'debug' => 1,
);
$jobby = new Jobby\Jobby( $config );
$serializer = new SuperClosure\Serializer();

$jobs = $model->getCronJobs();
foreach ( $jobs as $job )
{
    $job = array_filter( $job );

    try {
        $job['closure'] = $serializer->unserialize( $job['closure'] );
        unset( $job['command'] );
    } catch (SuperClosure\Exception\ClosureUnserializationException $e) {
    }

    $jobName = $job[ 'name' ];
    unset( $job[ 'name' ] );
    unset( $job[ 'id' ] );

    $jobby->add( $jobName, $job );
}

$jobby->run();
```

And what I get from `$model->getCronJobs();`:

```
array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(23) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(2) "11"
        ["name"]=>
        string(9) "testzcron"
        ["command"]=>
        string(1) " "
        ["closure"]=>
        string(243) "C:32:"SuperClosure\SerializableClosure":197:{a:5:{s:4:"code";s:                                                                                                                                                             102:"function () {
        echo 'I\'m a function (' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . ')!' . PHP_EOL;
        return true;
        };";s:7:"context";a:0:{}s:7:"binding";N;s:5:"scope";N;s:8:"isStatic";b:0;}}"
        ["schedule"]=>
        string(9) "* * * * *"
        ["mailer"]=>
        string(4) "smtp"
        ["maxRuntime"]=>
        NULL
        ["recipients"]=>
        NULL
        ["smtpHost"]=>
        NULL
        ["smtpPort"]=>
        NULL
        ["smtpUsername"]=>
        NULL
        ["smtpPassword"]=>
        NULL
        ["smtpSender"]=>
        string(15) "jobby@localhost"
        ["smtpSenderName"]=>
        string(5) "Jobby"
        ["smtpSecurity"]=>
        NULL
        ["runAs"]=>
        NULL
        ["environment"]=>
        NULL
        ["runOnHost"]=>
        NULL
        ["output"]=>
        NULL
        ["dateFormat"]=>
        string(11) "Y-m-d H:i:s"
        ["enabled"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["haltDir"]=>
        NULL
        ["debug"]=>
        string(1) "0"
    }
}
```

From `log` file:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'SuperClosure\Exception\ClosureUnserializationException' with message 'The closure did not unserialize to a SuperClosure.' in /home/.../public_html/vendor/jeremeamia/SuperClosure/src/Serializer.php:103
Stack trace:
#0 /home/.../public_html/vendor/hellogerard/jobby/src/BackgroundJob.php(233): SuperClosure\Serializer->unserialize('N;')
#1 /home/.../public_html/vendor/hellogerard/jobby/src/BackgroundJob.php(88): Jobby\BackgroundJob->runFunction()
#2 /home/.../public_html/vendor/hellogerard/jobby/bin/run-job(20): Jobby\BackgroundJob->run()
#3 {main}
thrown in /home/.../public_html/vendor/jeremeamia/SuperClosure/src/Serializer.php on line 103
```

## Edit:

`$serializer->unserialize( $job['closure'] );` is:

```
object(Closure)#9 (0) {
}
```

and when I call it it works perfectly fine:

```
root@test:/home/.../public_html/public# /usr/local/bin/php cron.php
I'm a function (2016-04-13 11:46:52)!
bool(true)
```

Comment: Could you log the result of `$serializer->unserialize( $job['closure'] );`?

Comment: @magnetik Added in edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that by unserializing the closure yourself (using SuperClosure) you're creating a different context for the closure, which can not be used to serialize it again. The long version:

SuperClosure uses Reflection; it accepts the Closure you pass and it figures out the php-file where this Closure was actually created. This is the only way to 'convert' the runtime Closure to serializable code, by storing the original source.

- By calling `$serializer->unserialize()` you are [indirectly](https://github.com/jeremeamia/super_closure/blob/6fe8ad066d3b2b01ad71d2130ebd38ccaabd549f/src/SerializableClosure.php#L210) using `eval()` to convert serialized to runtime
- This creates a new Closure (in runtime) which you can use (with the `eval` function as its source)
- However, **jobby** *also* [uses](https://github.com/jobbyphp/jobby/blob/af512864866b7fc5461535920ec6f39c2eaa27f1/src/Jobby.php#L193) SuperClosure to serialize this closure (from runtime)
- SuperClosure needs the source for this Closure, and [uses](https://github.com/jeremeamia/super_closure/blob/6fe8ad066d3b2b01ad71d2130ebd38ccaabd549f/src/Analyzer/ClosureAnalyzer.php#L16) [Reflection](http://php.net/ReflectionFunction) to find the code for your closure
- Instead of finding the actual source of the code, it finds the `eval()` that doesn't really contain this code

---

As for the solution, I think the best thing to do might be to remove this line:

```
$job['closure'] = $serializer->unserialize( $job['closure'] );
```

and convince Jobby to accept your SuperClosure directly; you might need to update Jobby like this:

```
     protected function getExecutableCommand($job, array $config)
     {
-        if (isset($config['closure'])) {
+        if (isset($config['closure']) && gettype($config['closure']) != 'string') {
             $config['closure'] = $this->getSerializer()->serialize($config['closure']);
         }
```

However, I have never used SuperClosure or Jobby and I can't really test this. Please let us know if this works.